# Why can structs conceal their implementation details but not enums?

Tags: struct, enums, rust, visibility

In [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-layout.html), they show that a `pub enum` can't hold a private `struct`:

```
struct Node {
    elem: i32,
    next: List,
}

pub enum List {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}
```

```
error[E0446]: private type `Node` in public interface
 --> src/lib.rs:8:10
  |
8 |     More(Box<Node>),
  |          ^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private type
```

They also show that you can have a `pub struct` hold a private `enum`

```
pub struct List {
    head: Link,
}

enum Link {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}
```

Why is this?